# Microsoft Outlook not setting times to p.m?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, time, events, appointments

When I go to add in a reoccurring appointment into Outlook it does not let me set the time to p.m? When I set the start time I have tried scrolling down on the arrow to 3 p.m and even typing/ changing a.m to p.m, each time it automatically changes to a.m.

I have recently updated iCloud and am wondering if this is the reason. Currently running Outlook 2007.

Someone able to help me get this sorted?

Comment: Have you tried removing the update to see if the problem stops?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but my solution to this was removing the upgrade to iCloud 2.* back down to the last installed version 1.* and that solved the issue with no further action needed.